# "other" turn into "NA"

Tags: r, levels

I have a data.frame (DL)  and one of the column name is fruit and it is like c("apple", "lemon", "orange", "others") so I want to change level this column so that the order of legend (when I create plot) will follow the order that I want. Here is my code

```
DL$fruit <- factor(DL$fruit, levels=c("lemon", "apple",  "orange", "others"))
```

But when I view this data after this using View(DL), the "others" will change to "NA". When I ggplot this and it will not show bar of "others". Does anyone have an idea what is going on and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a chance that there is extra whitespace in your `DL$fruit` column?

Comment: @AnandaMahto You are right! When I change to "others " from "others", it works. Thanks.

Comment: @kelvinfrog, OK. I've added it as an answer.

Comment: I always use `names(table(var))` to check for disguised whitespace (especially when it shows up some times but not others)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sometimes happens if your data are not quite clean--for example, if you have extra whitespace around the input values.

Here's an example:

```
fruit <- c("apple", "lemon", "orange", "others", "others ") ## note the last two values
factor(fruit, levels=c("lemon", "apple",  "orange", "others"))
# [1] apple  lemon  orange others <NA>  
# Levels: lemon apple orange others
```

Now, let's strip out the whitespace:

```
newFruit <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", fruit)
factor(newFruit, levels = unique(newFruit))
# [1] apple  lemon  orange others others
# Levels: apple lemon orange others
```

---

If you want to inspect the source data and look for whitespace, sometimes it helps to use `print`, with `quote = TRUE`:

```
print(fruit, quote = TRUE)
# [1] "apple"   "lemon"   "orange"  "others"  "others "
```

Alternatively, `grepl` could also be of use:

```
grepl("^\\s+|\\s+$", fruit)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```